# Reorder array of Dictionary By swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm working on ios app by swift!

An i need to display the data from the array of dictionary order by the price value.
How can i reorder this array

```
(
        {
        price = 269600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 294600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 1345600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 287600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 1344600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 1343600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 1333600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 1332600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 1322600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 322600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 302600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 300600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 291600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 282600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    },
        {
        price = 299600;
        userid = "facebook:851661711521620";
    }
)
```

to be ordered by price from The highest to The lowest?
i need to display the data to be like this

[image]

Any ideas how can i do it Thanks!

Thanks!

Edited add some actual code.

```
self.currentBidDict = snapshot.value["current_bid_id"] as! NSDictionary

for(var i = 0;i <= self.currentBidDict.count - 1;i++){
    self.currentBidDictReOrder.insertObject(self.currentBidDict.allValues[i], atIndex: 0)
    println(self.currentBidDictReOrder)
}
```

Then after i printIn i got array above in the question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function, `sort`, that takes any sequence, and returns a sorted array.  Since dictionaries are sequences of `(key,value)` pairs, you can pass the dictionary in to sort.

If what you pass in isn’t naturally sortable (i.e. the elements of the sequence are `Comparable`, which dictionaries aren’t), you need to also supply a closure telling `sort` how to order the elements.  In your case, you want that closure to compare the value for a specific key in the dictionaries.

Finally, you want to sort by a value, but looking up a key in a dictionary returns an optional (because the key might not be there).  But, this is fine!  Because optionals have a `<` operator that works, so long as what the optional contains is comparable.  Except, it looks like you’ve got a dictionary of `Any` or `AnyObject` (because you have both strings and integers in there), so you’ll have to covert them to something you can compare.

Put it all together and:

```
sorted(dict) { ($0["price"] as? Int) > ($1["price"] as? Int) }
```

You might want to tweak that `as?` a bit depending on what your dictionary actually contains.  Also, I’d strongly suggest looking at creating a more strongly-typed struct and populating that with your data, rather than leaving it in dictionary form like this.

Comment: i got overload for 'sorted' that accepts an argument list of type

Comment: You need to post actual code, it’s impossible to tell you the precise syntax without knowing the real types involved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sort` function in the following way:

```
var dict =  [[
        "price" : 1111,
        "userid" : "facebook:851661711521620"
        ],
        [
        "price" : 12222,
        "userid" : "facebook:851661711521620"
        ],
        [
        "price" : 144444,
        "userid" : "facebook:851661711521620"
        ]]       

// sort by price 
dict.sort {
    x, y in
    let item1 = x["price"] as! Int
    let item2 = y["price"] as! Int
    return item1 > item2
}
```

And the output should be like this:

```
[[price: 144444, userid: facebook:851661711521620], [price: 12222, userid: facebook:851661711521620], [price: 1111, userid: facebook:851661711521620]]
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Wouldn't `sorted(dictionary) { $0.0 < $1.0 }` be enough? There's no real need to give them names, cast them to Int and compare them no?

Comment: @JacobsonTalom If you do what you said then you have a compilation error like this `Cannot find an overload for 'sorted' that accepts an argument list of type '([Dictionary<String, NSObject>], (_, _) -> _)'` because the `sort`, `sorted` function don't know how are the elements inside. Try it for yourself

Comment: its late, i should go to bed.. :p My bad.

Comment: there’s no need to force-unwrap, optionals can be compared with `>` directly

Comment: i tried self.currentBidDictReOrder.sort { x, y in let item1 = x["price"] as! Int let item2 = y["price"] as! Int return item1 > item2 } but still got NSmutablearray doesn't have a member name sort?

Comment: @VarisDarasirikul Put the real representation of the data as I do, to see how your data is represented.